# How to CI build branches in VSTS

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, pull-request

We use Git repositories in **VSTS** with branches and **Pull Requests** model to allow Code Reviews.

We have a **CI Build** definition and following it **Release** definition for all commits pushed to master.

And it would be a huge bonus if we can do **CI for all branches** too.
However Build definition for Git repos allows to setup only single branch to track.

And creating a Build per branch isn't feasible, as our branches are short-living aka feature branches and we delete them after PR merge to master.

Yes, there is an ability to specify to run **CI build for PRs** to master in **Branch Policies** page. But there are 2 issues with this:

- this will build only PR, while we want to build all the individual commits in branches as soon as they are pushed there
- CI build for PRs will trigger our Release too, but we obviously want it to be triggered only for master builds. Yes I can analyze `$(Build.SourceBranch)` or `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` in the Release definition and fail if it's not "master" but it will create a failed Release anyway, which I just want to avoid at all

So... how can we have CI builds in VSTS for any arbitrary branch?

---

### Update

Another idea wrt running Release only for master builds - is to trigger Release from the Build side, e.g. [by using API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#create-a-release) if `$(Build.SourceBranch)` equals to 'master', say by custom PowerShell script.

I can see there's even an extension for [VSTS Trigger build step](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergiibomko.vsts-trigger), but it will trigger even for non-master builds, although Microsoft is working on [a feature to run steps conditionally](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8623600-allow-build-vnext-preview-tasks-to-be-conditionall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a powershell script task at the end of your build definition to trigger the release via Rest API, I created a simple code sample for your reference:

```
if ($env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME -eq "master")
{
$collectionuri = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
$buildid = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$project = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
$builddef = $env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME
$buildnum = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$releaseid = 2;

#Generate API URL
$account = "";
$reg = "https://+(?<acc>\w+?).visualstudio+"
if ($collectionuri -match $reg)
{
    $account = $Matches.acc;
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Fail to get the account name from collection url";
}
$url= "https://" + $account + ".vsrm.visualstudio.com/"+ $project + "/_apis/release/releases?api-version=3.0-preview.2"

#Generate Auth info
$basicAuth= ("{0}:{1}"-f "anys",$token)
$basicAuth=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers= @{Authorization=("Basic {0}"-f $basicAuth)}

#Generate body content
$instanceRef = @{id = $buildID};
$artif = @{alias = $builddef; instanceReference = @{id = $buildnum}}
$content = @{
    definitionId = $releaseid
    description = "Triggered from CI Build"
    artifacts = @($artif)
    }
$json = $content | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

#Call Rest API to start the release
$responseBuild = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -headers $headers -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Not master branch, no release triggered"
}
```

You need to update the "releaseid" to the id of the release definition you'd like to trigger and in the security configuration of that definition, set the "Create releases" permission to "Allow" for "Project Collection Build Service" account.

Comment: Brilliant script and usage of the env vars - does the job! Just a minor comment - in regex I've replaced \w with [\w-] as our account name contains a hyphen.

Comment: Also, to be able to use SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN I had to enable option 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' for the Build definition. Not a big deal, but still need to configure it for all builds. So wondering if there is a way to use -UsedefaultCredential option for Invoke-RestMethod instead of using access token? Tried but failed - it returnes some HTML complaining about Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration, instead of JSON

Answer (score 2):

> However Build definition for Git repos allows to setup only single branch to track.

That's actually not true. (You may be confused by the fact that the `Repository` tab has a `Default branch` setting, which only accepts a single branch.)

On the build definition, go to the `Triggers` tab. Check the `Continuous Integration` box if it isn't already.

Under `Branch filters` click `Add new filter` and set the value to `*`. (It will prompt you to select an existing branch, but you can ignore that and just hit Enter.)

Your build definition will now build commits on any branch in your repo.

Comment: Hi Scott... Yes, realized this after I posted a question. However it doesn't help us - a) we need to keep updating Build definition for each new branch (several a day); b) Release will still be triggered with these non-master builds.

Comment: @Ivan What do you mean by (a)? For (b), what I have done is create one Build definition that triggers the Release, and one for all other branches (which doesn't trigger a Release).

Comment: Ha, sorry, missed your point about star (*), tested it now and yes it works! Thanks.

Comment: With regards to (b) to have 2 Build definitions per repository is doable, we thought of this, but it still adds a bit of complexity - to maintain an additional definition, e.g. when we modify it we'd need to do it twice, and also amount of Build definitions in the VSTS project will double.

Comment: BTW see Update above I put to the question - about idea to trigger Release from the Build side.

Comment: @Ivan You can set a custom condition on a build step to only publish artefacts for master builds - that way the other CI builds don't trigger a release

Answer (score 0):

Very very easy.

1. Go to the Marketplace and install `GitVersion` into VSTS/Azure DevOps
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion
2. As what was described before, change your CI trigger to monitor all branches:
   [image]

   The reason I also add line #2 to monitor tags is because I leverage GitVersion and git tags to version the build artifact when I'm ready to release my product.  When I apply and push a git tag the build doesn't detect it unless I explicitly tell it to watch for it.  My format for git tag is "v1.2.3" starting with lower-case "v".  Just in case I want to apply any other tag and not start a build.
3. Lastly change the build number format.  You need to discern what branch is building.  GitVersion uses semantic versioning thus this describes what is building.

[image]

4. Now kick off as many builds from any number of branches and see them all kick off from a single build definition.  Set once and forget from now on!
   [image]

Benefits:

- No scripts to maintain
- Follow semantic versioning
- Create a build pipeline/definition once and never have to worry about feature branches every again.
- Will still work for Pull Requests.
- Read more about GitVersion at https://gitversion.readthedocs.io

The secret sauce:  GitVersion reads the Git history, so the number increments for every git commit AFTER it is tagged. It creates build variables from the CI system it is using and makes them available.  It derives these variables and creates a `tag` or alias for the branch it is building depending on the `mode` you are using GitVersion in.  In the example above I had some commits (not shown), when it was version `0.1.0` then I tagged it version `1.0.0` and released it.  The next commit predicted that the next version would be `1.1.0` and there were lots of commits (11 of them) into the `develop` branch.  The build name uses the alias `alpha` since build artifacts are alpha candidates.  There were 4 more commits.  There was a feature branch build after that branched from commit #15, made a 16th commit and pushed that, and was built.  I think you are getting the idea.  It's all from one single build pipeline and using GitVersion to describe what branch is being build and the commit being built.  Semantic versioning describes the build.